# TypeError '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str' - Pipeline Prediction

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, spacy

I'm trying to do sentiment analysis on a string using Spacy 2.3.5 and latest version of Python. This is the code that I'm using:

```
# Use the punctuations of string module
import string

# Pandas library to create our model from reviews txt files
import pandas as pd

# Spacy library to lemmatize and tokenize our reviews
import spacy

# ML Packages
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Splitting Data Set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Creating a Spacy Parser in english language
import en_core_web_sm
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

# Load our dataset
# Renaming Column Headers Message and Target (1 == Is Positive, 0 == Is Negative)
df_yelp = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv('/FileStore/tables/yelp_labelled.txt').withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'Message').withColumnRenamed('_c1','Target').select("*").toPandas()
df_imdb = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv('/FileStore/tables/imdb_labelled.txt').withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'Message').withColumnRenamed('_c1','Target').select("*").toPandas()
df_amz = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv('/FileStore/tables/amazon_cells_labelled.txt').withColumnRenamed('_c0', 'Message').withColumnRenamed('_c1','Target').select("*").toPandas()

# Concatenate our Datasets
frames = [df_yelp, df_imdb, df_amz]


# Assign a Key to Make it Easier
keys = ['Yelp', 'IMDB', 'Amazon']

# Merge or Concat our Datasets
df = pd.concat(frames, keys=keys)

# We than create our csv file with our column (SOURCE NAME, NUMBER, MESSAGE, VALUE)
df.to_csv("sentimentdataset.csv")

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

stopwords = list(STOP_WORDS)

punctuations = string.punctuation

# We will use an english parser for the sentences
parser = English()

def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    mytokens = parser(sentence)
    mytokens = [word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens]
    mytokens = [word for word in mytokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations]
    return mytokens

# Basic function to clean the text
def clean_text(text):
    return text.strip().lower()
  
# Custom transformer using spaCy
class predictors(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X):
        return [clean_text(text) for text in X]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self


# CountVectorizer implements both tokenization and occurrence counting in a single class:
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=spacy_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1, 1))

# We use a linear algorithm classification
classifier = LinearSVC()

# Features Column Name. This is the column with the message
X = df['Message']

# This is the column name with the value 1 or 0, Positive or Negative
ylabels = df['Target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, ylabels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create the  pipeline to clean, tokenize, vectorize, and classify
pipe = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictors()), ('vectorizer', vectorizer), ('classifier', classifier)])

# Fit our data because we have to unify the trained data column together
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

# NOW WE CAN START TO PREDICT THE SENTIMENT OF THE PEOPLE WHO WRITE REVIEWS

# Another random review
example = ["Test string"]

print(pipe.predict(example))
```

During the training of the classifier on the line `pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)`, I receive the following error: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'".

The detailed error is as follow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1852731017614759> in <module>
     93 
     94 # Fit our data because we have to unify the trained data column together
---> 95 pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
     96 
     97 # NOW WE CAN START TO PREDICT THE SENTIMENT OF THE PEOPLE WHO WRITE REVIEWS

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    333             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    334                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 335                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    336 
    337         return self

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/svm/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    228                                    dtype=np.float64, order="C",
    229                                    accept_large_sparse=False)
--> 230         check_classification_targets(y)
    231         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
    232 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     y : array-like
    168     """
--> 169     y_type = type_of_target(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    288         return 'continuous' + suffix
    289 
--> 290     if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
    291         return 'multiclass' + suffix  # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
    292     else:

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    259     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    260     if axis is None:
--> 261         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    262         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    263 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    320         aux = ar[perm]
    321     else:
--> 322         ar.sort()
    323         aux = ar
    324     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)
```

How can I solve the problem?

[EDIT]
The problem was with the file amazon_cells_labelled.txt. Removing the relative DataFrame solved the problem.

Comment: Does `np.unique(y_train)` fail with the same message?  What is the contents of `y_train`?

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes, `np.unique(y_train)` return the same error. The content of y_train is the following:

Yelp  642    1
      700    0
      226    1
IMDB  697    0
      10     1
            ..
      638    1
      95     1
      130    0
      294    1
Yelp  860    1
Name: Target, Length: 2400, dtype: object

Comment: Presumably some of the entries are actually missing (`np.nan` or `None`), causing the error.  But those entries are all strange; are you sure they make sense?  What do the numbers represent?

Comment: Your target doesn't feel right. If you're doing classification these should be classes, not  `Yelp 642 1 700 0 226 1 IMDB 697 0 10 1 .. 638 1 95 1 130 0 294 1 Yelp 860 1 ` Please update your question with what you have in target column or link the file

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that when you perform your text preprocessing, you eliminate certain rows (it sometimes happens that some rows contain all the words you want to remove). So you end up with your X_train with fewer rows than your y_train (these rows will appear as None), which translates to the NoneType vs. str error you received.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you provide an example on how to do that please?

Comment: What I would do is take a look at your spacy_tokenizer function. That's where you perform operations to remove certain words. I'd apply that function on your text corpus (X_train) and see if the final results has the same shape as the original X_train.

Comment: I also saw that your y_train contains both numbers and strings. Can you specify the structure of your y_train? is it a vector? or a matrix?